# Is it possible to change the internal hashing function of Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hash

I am trying to write a program which uses Locality Sensitivity Hashing and [CityHash](https://pypi.org/project/cityhash/) to perform a double hash on strings (Kmers) in order to find similarity between long gene sequences. I've been able to achieve the original objective of the program without this additional requirement as well, but I want to know if it can be done to improve efficiency. As part of its implementation, I want to try to modify the inherent hashing done by Python dictionaries and use my DoubleHash function so that I can reduce redundancy.

My DoubleHash function is as follows

```
def DoubleHash(self, rawShingle: str) -> int:
    '''
    Subsampling the shingle and hashing it to yield the same hash value for very similar shingles
    '''
        
    subSet = ''
    for i in self.randList:
        subSet += rawShingle[i]

    hash_value = CityHash32(subSet)
        
    return hash_value
```

Where self.randList is a list of random indices to take a subsample of the original string passed to it.

I am trying to intentionally cause collisions here so that I can hash similar strings to the same hash and then compare them later on by referencing my custom dictionary keys, which will be the hash value given to them.

```
class CustomDict(UserDict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value) -> None:
        '''
        Sets Hash:[Kmer, ] pair to dictionary
        '''

        key = CityHash32(key)

        if key in self.data:
            self.data[key].append(value) # Hashing similar Kmers to the same Hash
        else:
            self.data[key] = [value, ] # Storing [Kmer, ]

        return

    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> list:
        '''
        Gets list of Kmers corresponding to Hash
        '''

        try:
            return self.data[key] # Returning [Kmer, ]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        raise KeyError(key)

    def __getkey__(self, value: list) -> int:
        '''
        Gets Hash corresponding to list of Kmers
        '''

        for i in range(len(self.data)):

            if value in self.data[i]: # Checking for input Kmer in [Kmer, ]

                index = i # returning index of corresponding Hash:[Kmer, ] pair
                break

        return self.data.keys()[index] # Returning Hash
```

This is the first attempt I have made at this, but I want to try and use the internal hashes that Python uses for its dictionaries to implement this. Is there any way that I can replace Python's [hash()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-hash-method/) method with my own methods rather than just inheriting from dict or UserDict?

Comment: If you create your own class and use instances of that class as dictionary keys, you can implement the `__hash__` method in your class. That means that `hash(obj)` will return your custom hash.

Comment: Do you want a dictionary with custom hashing/indexing or do you really want instances of your object to use a custom hash to identify it?

Comment: It is the former, a dictionary with custom hashing/indexing. I want to try and use Python's inbuilt hashing for dictionaries instead of explicitly declaring keys as hashes and values as lists of strings corresponding to said hashes.